# Selective drupal database dump

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I have a drupal application that has:

1. 100 content types
2. Initial nodes are application's master nodes
3. Db size is 50GB

What I want? 
I want to setup this application on another server but just want master nodes in it. How do I take MySQL backup in such a way that entire drupal application structure is dumped and only master nodes are inserted. I want all content types but only masters to be populated.

Its a problem because on our local environment too, we have to dump entire 50GB. Ideally we only want all content types (just structure and no nodes) and just the masters.

Please suggest some solutions/suggestions.

Comment: Are the master nodes in different tables than the data that you don't want to copy? If so, use MySQL table replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rules-table-options.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. All content types and nodes are in same database. Also, replication won't be possible on local environments. Devs need to update there local machines. And updation involves inserting full database on local machines.